# How do I install dpkg on the iPhone, manually?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, dpkg

Assuming I have SSH access to my phone but dpkg is not installed, how can I do so, manually?

Comment: Not appropriate for this website.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install dkpg` over ssh